# How to get table names from Presto query using presto-parser?

Tags: presto

Not able to extract table names used within ***with*** clause, I'm using presto-parser version 0.226.

```
        SqlParser sqlParser = new SqlParser();
        String sql = "WITH dataset AS ( SELECT ROW('Bob', 38) AS users from tabb ) SELECT * FROM dataset";

        Query query = (Query)sqlParser.createStatement(sql, ParsingOptions.builder().build());
        QuerySpecification body = (QuerySpecification)query.getQueryBody();

        System.out.println("From = " + body.getFrom().get());
    /* Output
      From = Table{dataset}
    */
     Expected output
     From = Table{dataset, tabb}
```

Comment: I would recommend using Presto server instance for extracting table names. You can run `EXPLAIN (TYPE IO) <query>` and it will give you JSON document which is easy to process in machine-friendly way. (Whether you consider this an answer or not, it's up to you. I can convert this to answer if you want me to.)

Comment: Thank @PiotrFindeisen, But explain will not help us since we are capturing the queries to analysis before it can run on AWS Athena. And Athena doesn't support explain statement.